# PayPal create_order_error cannot read properties of null

Tags: paypal, .net-6.0

I've integrated PayPal into my .NET 6 (Blazor) application. I followed the [PayPal docs here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addpaymentbuttons) to add the button. In test mode all worked fine. Now that I've changed the `clientid` to live I get an error:

> `create_order_error` Cannot read properties of null

[image]

I can see the token is `null`, but I'm not sure what to do about it?

The code I'm using to create the order is here:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    // Style the button
    style: {
      ...
    },

    // Called when the button is clicked
    onClick: function (data, actions) {
      ...
    },

    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: document.getElementById('p-amount').value,
          }
        }]
      });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      ...
    },

    onError: function () {
      ...
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I have searched for this error but it didn't generate any results. Any help on how to resolve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> document.getElementById('p-amount')

Is null. Make it be something that's not null.

Comment: Wow! You're right I edited that element and mistakenly removed the id. Thank you